# How would I rig an ammo belt?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I would to rig an ammo belt so that one end moves while the other stays still like the images below

[image]
[image]
Credit to Sibience on sketchfab for the APU model

[Sketchfab animations](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/matrix-apu-8cadc345c93c4d2bbfdcfa328d6e3cf8) showing how exactly I would like it to move:

I would like to stick to bones and not use curves so I can add physics to it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this sort of solution: Create a plane, subdivide it, select the edges at each extremity and assign them to a vertex group called *pin group*. Create your armature, create a bone at each extremity of the plane, parent the plane to the armature *With Empty Groups*, assign the edges at each extremity to the bone it is supposed to be controlled by. Give a *Cloth* simulation to your plane, under *Shape > Pin Group*, select the pin group you've created:

[image]

You can use this plane as the *Surface Deform* object of a more complicated belt. To create the bullets, select the plane, in the *Object panel > Instancing*, enable *Faces*, you can disable *Show Instancer > Viewport* and *Render* if you don't want to see the plane. Create a bullet, parent it to the plane. Animate the bones, here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: This has worked perfect for me so far! One question, how would i get the bullets to stop deforming? they are squishing when the belt moves and not giving the same effect as in the gif you posted. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you've used the instancing method they should not deform, maybe share your file?

Comment: [File to my belt model here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/9z28xq9hchi50qm/BeltPrototype.blend/file)

Comment: The belt is stretched, apply its scale